# LinqToSql Custom Classes Derived from Multiple Database tables

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

in my db I have two tables that are related. Lets call them Job and JobType
Job has a foreign key jobTypeID that references JobType.

I would like to create a custom class in the dbml with properties from both of the DB tables...essentially all of the Job properties and the JobTypeName property from JobType

This is a simplified example but id like to know if this is even possible before I continue.

Ultimately I need a linqtosql class with the appropriate properties to pass to a parser which handles paging, sorting, etc for a client side data grid...

If it helps to point me in a better direction, the parser takes an IQueryable with a generic type...the type being the linqtosql class that holds the data that will be displayed in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since all your tables got relations and successfully transferred to the DBML then yes you can do that

basically create a partial class for you Job class (partial class to refer to the Job class created by Linq Designer) and put a property inside it that returns the JobTypeName from referenced table

e.g.:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Partial class for job class created by LINQ Desinger
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Job
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Property to return the JobTypeName for this Job
        /// </summary>
        public string JobTypeName
        {
            get
            {
                if (JobType != null)
                    return this.JobType.JobTypeName;
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Well I did get this to work but not the way I had intitially imagined...

I was able to create a view in the db to return the columns needed then map the view to a linqtosql class.

Performance seems to be OK for the time being.

I am guessing the proper approach would be to explore ado.net entity framework for future projects

Comment: accepted different answer but this solution did work for me in a pinch.